# what's the difference between variable and process from a statistical point of view?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, intuition, average

I'm reading a tutorial **stochastic process: ergodicity and temporal averages** and I'm totally confused. It is said that:

> Suppose an IID random process whose marginal PDF is Gaussian with mean
>   and variance equal 1.   let $X_i[18]$ denote the $i$th realization at
>   time $n = 18$, then by definition $$\lim_{M\to +\infty}\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M x_m[18]=E[X[18]]=\mu_X[18]=\mu=1$$ is called `averaging down the ensemble` and consequently is just a restatement of our usual notion of
>   the expected value of a random variable
>   However, if we are given only a single realization such as $x_i[n]$, then it seems reasonable that $$\hat\mu_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_1[n]$$ should also converge to $\mu$ as $N\to\infty$

Since I am not educated enough in stochastic processes, I'm stuck with lots of maybe elementary problems that make me confused and I don't know where to start on the web to study about because whenever I google the term, I encounter with some new terms that I don't understand the meaning of them so help me as if you are illustrating these concepts to a layman or your grand mum as Einstein says.
My knowledge in statistics is in the level of what I have studied in the first year of college for the course `probability and statistics in engineering` and few other courses for the adjustment of errors. I've never even heard of terms such ergodicity and etc. But I do need the concept in my study now.

**My questions:**

```
1- what does Independent and identically distributed random process mean?  

2-what's the difference of random process with random variable?

3-Is there a difference between stochastic process and random process? 

4-Is there a difference between stochastic variable and random variable?  

5-what does the realization of a random process mean?  

6-Is the first equation equal to `ensemble average`?
```

please provide examples and simplification in your answers as much as you can as if you are illustrating the concept to a layman

---

For example:
1-Tossing the die is an example of a random process;
2-The number on top of the die is an example of random variable.
Could you please explain me how to compute the `ensemble average` and `temporal average` of `tossing a die`? What does realization mean in this specific example?

Answer (score 2):

First, *random* and *stochastic* are synonyms.

A stochastic process is a collection of random variables $X=(X_i)_{i\in I}$.

You have two important cases:

- the discrete case: $I=\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ (or a subset of those). Then the process is a *sequence* of random variables.
- the continuous case : $I=\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,+\infty )$ for example. Then the stochastic process is a *random function*.

As you may know, a random variable is a measurable function $\Omega\rightarrow S$ where $S$ is a measurable space. Then there are two points of view regarding stochastic processes. You can see them as a collection of random variables indexed by the set $I$. Or you can see them as a single random variable with a bigger $S$.

For example, let's say you have a stochastic process $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $X_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Then you can see $X$ as a random variable with $S$ the set of all real-valued sequences.
You can write $X=X(\omega ,n)$. If you fix $\omega$, you obtain a real-valued sequence which is called a realization of $X$ (or a trajectory). If you fix $n$ (the time for example), you obtain the real-values random variable $X_n$.

Comment: what do you mean by the collection of random variables? For example X is the result of tossing a die and Y is the result of flipping a coin which are random variables. how can you define a random process by these random variables?

Comment: In most applications, $I$ represents time and is usually infinite. If you toss a dice each day and denote by $X_1$ the result of the first day, $X_2$ the result of the second day and so on, you obtain a stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. If you have a dice and a coin and if you keep track of the results of both each day, you obtain a multivariate stochastic process $(X_n,Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}. But we'll not call just $(X,Y)$ a stochastic process, it's just a random vector.

Comment: In your example above for example after 30 days we have a random process such $X=(X_i)_{1\le i\le 30}$ now if we sum up the results of 30 days and divide it by 30 it is called temporal averaging. but if we sum up all the possible results of a single day and divide it by 6 it is called ensemble average which is $\frac{(1+2+3+4+5+6)}{6}=\frac{21}{6}$ for all these 30 days so we can say tossing a die on subsequent days is an wide sense stationary process because it's average does not depend on time. now if we suppose $X=(X_i)_{1\le i\le 30}$ as a random variable with $6^{30}$ possible outcomes it

Comment: will be called a realization. or if we consider $X=(X_i)_{5\le i\le 10}$ an random variable with $6^6$ outcomes, it is another realization. But if we fix the day we get a random variable. $f(X_i)=\frac{1}{6}$ which is the probability of a certain result in each day is the marginal PDF of the process. Are my conclusions true?

Comment: It's actually more than wide-sense stationary, it is an i.i.d. sequence. I think you misunderstood what a realization is. A realization is just the result you observe. If you toss a dice and you obtain $X=2$, then $2$ is the realization of $X$. Now if you have $X=(X_i)_{1\leq i\leq 4}$, a realization could be $(5,2,3,1)$. Another one may be $(2,6,5,3)$.
Yes the marginals are the individual random variables of the process.

Comment: thanks! And are my inferences about temporal averaging and ensemble averaging true?

Comment: Yes I think you understood the two ways of averaging a stochastic process. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process there is another definition of stationarity which i think is a bit more intuitive.